# Neural network for iris data set

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, sigmoid

Background: I'm writing in Python a three-layer neural network using mini-batch stochastic gradient descent specifically designed to identify between three classes of iris plants from the famous [iris data set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set). The input layer has four neurons, one for each feature in the data. The hidden layer has 3 neurons (but the code allows variations in hidden layer neuron numbers) and the output layer has three neurons (one for each species). All neurons use sigmoid activation functions.

Problem: The loss (mean-squared error) generally decreases over time, however the accuracy (usually below 55.55% or even 33.33%) is stagnant. I've tried experimenting with different epoch iteration numbers and learning rates, but nothing worked. Interestingly, more often than not, the outputs for the algorithm remain fixed no matter what the input values are. I'm fairly certain of my math, since the loss seems to be decreasing as the number of epochs increases.

To replicate problem: Just run the Python code and observe the LEARNING_RESULTS.txt file. (Make sure iris.txt file in the repo is in same directory)

Question: How can I improve performance for this neural network?

Link to GitHub repo: https://github.com/kwonkyo/neural-networks

Thanks!

UPDATE: Problem solved. I was adding a constant value (numerical sum of the sum of the mini-batch matrices) to the weight and bias matrices instead of the sum of the mini-batch gradient matrices. Updated code has been pushed to github.

Comment: Try more hidden neurons. If the loss is decreasing, but the accuracy is not, often the model is somehow inadequate.

Comment: I found the problem: when I was updating the weight and bias derivatives, instead of doing a matrix addition between the weight matrix and the gradient matrix, I made the error of adding the sum of the gradient matrix instead. For some reason, numpy allowed me to add a matrix and a number. Fixing this gave me around 98% accuracy! This is so fun.

Comment: (I had tried adding more hidden neurons before, but it didn't improve the results)